# Possible soap version mismatch in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I want to create an api with wso2ei6.3. after creating api as below :

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Test" context="/Test" version="/" version-type="context">
 <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/CheckTest" inSequence="GetUserInfo">
  <outSequence>
     <send/>
  </outSequence>
 </resource>
</api>
```

I send message to "GetUserInfo" sequence. in "GetUserInfo" sequence i get property of user input and send it in to a soap service as the fallowing :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="GetUserInfo" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
 <property expression="$trp:Token" name="Token" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
 <property action="remove" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2"/>
 <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
        <p:GetUserInfo xmlns:p="http://tempuri.org/">
            <s1:token xmlns:s1="http://tempuri.org/">$1</s1:token>
        </p:GetUserInfo>
    </format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:Token" literal="false" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    </args>
 </payloadFactory>
 <send receive="GetUserPermission">
    <endpoint>
        <address uri="soap service endpoint"/>
    </endpoint>
 </send>
</sequence>
```

but i get fallowing error when sending message to endpoint:

```
<faultcode>soap:VersionMismatch</faultcode><faultstring>Possible SOAP version mismatch: Envelope namespace http://tempuri.org/ was unexpected. Expecting http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/.</faultstring>
```

do i should change my namespace of payload?

Comment: Have you verified whether you are able to fetch token ? if yes then next try replacing send mediator with call and check if you get the same error,If you get the same error then verify whether you are passing the request properly along with headers , first test the web service via soap UI and see what all parameters and version the web service is accepting if you are passing same from wso2 ei

Comment: I am able to fetch token and check it with soap UI and replace with payload factory but i get same error. i don't know what header namespace should i send to endpoint exactly?

Comment: Can you paste the raw data when you pass from SOAP UI, and debug logs of wso2 when you are testing.That should give a good idea on what is going wrong

Answer (score 1):

Seems like WSO2 does not put your message in SOAP envelope.
Your backend service does not recognize it as the top level element has a namespace different from "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/". 
May be you should use named Address endpoint with exact format "SOAP1.1" instead of inline endpoint with uri.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with add this 3 property before send:

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/soap+xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
<property name="ContentType" value="application/soap+xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
<property name="CONTENT_TYPE" value="application/soap+xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
```